# Hal+Json PagedRepresentationList Links using WebApi.Hal

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

This is a tough question to ask or explain. Im using the WebApi.Hal libraries for a C# MVC WebApi.

The return response looks like this

```
"TotalResults": 4,
"TotalPages": 1,
"Page": 1,
"_links": {
    "movies": [{
        "href": "/movies/2"
    },
    {
        "href": "/movies/4"
    },
    {
        "href": "/movies/8"
    },
    {
        "href": "/movies/15"
    }]
```

I do not want an Array of movies to be in the _links rel. I would like to know if there is a way to get rid of them. I the movie representation i use, all i do in terms of links in override the Href

```
    public override string Href
    {
        get { return LinkTemplates.Movies.Movie.CreateLink(new { id = movieId }).Href; }
    }
```

Thanks for any responses.

Comment: It's not clear what is the problem. Please provide more examples of your code.

Comment: Can you show us the classes to which you are trying to deserialize?